# Is an open subscheme of an open subscheme of $X$ an open subscheme of $X$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

Given $X=Spec(\mathcal O(X))$ is an affine scheme, the hyperplane-complement 
$D_f=Spec(\mathcal O(X)[\frac{1}{f}])$ is an open subscheme of $X$($D_f$ denotes the complement of $Z_f$). If I have an open subscheme of $D_f$, is it an open subscheme of $X$?

More generally, for any $D_I$ which is the complement of $Z_I\subseteq X$, for an open subschem of $D_I$, is it an open subscheme of $X$?

I am not sure for this. A proof or some explaination would be very appreciated.

To prove an open subscheme $D_I$ for $I\subseteq \mathcal O(X)[1/f]$ is an open subscheme of $X$, I think what I need to do is to conclude $D_I=D_{I'}$ for some $I'\subseteq \mathcal O(X)$. So may I please for an explaination which is elementary like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your open subsubscheme $U \subset D_f$ is covered by principal open subschemes of $D_f$ because their underlying topological supports are a basis for the topology of $D_f$.

Moreover a principal open subscheme $(D_f)_g$ of a principal open subscheme $D_f$ of an affine scheme $S$ is also a principal open subscheme of $S$, you have in fact that $(D_f)_g=D_{fg}=Spec (O(X)[\frac{1}{fg}])$.

So $U$ is covered by open subschemes and so it is an open subscheme.

In the general case of $D_I$ you can reduce to the open principal subsets once again using the fact that principal open subsets are a basis for the topology.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it gives me the desired conclusion. But I have not exposed to the theory of "basis" and "principle open subscheme". To prove an open subscheme $D_I$ for $I\subseteq \mathcal O(X)[1/f]$ is an open subscheme of $X$, I think what I need to do is to conclude $D_I=D_{I'}$ for some $I'\subseteq \mathcal O(X)$(That is, use the definition of the pen scheme). If possible, may I please for a rather elementary explaination?

Comment: Topologically the principal open subsets are a basis for the zarisky topology on the spectrum of a ring. It is an easy exercise you can find in a basic topology book.

Comment: A principal open is an open of the form $D_f$